# Rollup Field Decimal throwing error

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, calculated-field, rollup, dynamics-crm-365-v9

I´ve got a rollup field calculating a decimal value, its working fine, but when i recalculate it im getting an error message.

[image]

None of the values being calculated are null nor another type.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The error looks like value exceeds the max/min range..

Comment: Hi Arun,  the value is less than the range by far! thanks, L

Comment: can you translate the error message into English & update the question with error message + sample values you are getting in calculation?